# Bitmap Resource Res Cannot be Resolved

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I basically have a class within another class (child). I'm trying to get the width of a bitmap  that's in my "drawable" folder. I though this would be a simple operation but of course anything with android development isn't simple :-/

Anyhow the code I've tried is:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPurgeable = true;
this._backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources res,com.forwardapps.tanks.R.drawable.battlefield, options);
```

The error is: "Resources cannot be resolved to a variable". I've got no idea what's suppose to go into this field? A resource of what?

If you can solve this it would save me a great deal of time! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
this._backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources res,com.forwardapps.livetanks.R.drawable.battlefield, options);
```

Note the first parameter of `decodeResource`. It should be:

```
this._backgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,com.forwardapps.livetanks.R.drawable.battlefield, options);
```

Comment: I get the same error message but with "Res cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Does res exist? I think the problem is you are too noob to Java (that's not bad, everyone was a noob). You should follow a quick tutorial first, before learning Android.

Comment: Then `res` is clearly not declared as a variable. Assuming this code is within an activity, you can do: `Resources res = getResources();` before this, but it sounds like you might want to go through some basic programming tutorials so that you can really understand what's going on.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I'm getting 
    The method getResources() is undefined for the type Battlefield

I don't have time to go though tutorials, I learn as I go + I've almost finished the app, just having problems with bitmaps :-(

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I figured it out! Had the relay the context (reference) from the parent during the initialization of the child class.

For anyone who is stuck ^^